# how i can insert file into blob001 column in apex collection table by dynamic action

Tags: oracle-apex

how i can insert blob file into apex collection table by dynamic action .

I tried   that  but the bellow error in image appeared how i can solve this issue, 
and i tried that by the below code but the NO_DATA_FOUND  error Appeared  ALSO .

```
  DECLARE 
  V_BLOB BLOB;
  BEGIN
  select  BLOB_CONTENT  
  into V_BLOB  
  from apex_application_temp_files  
  where name = :P13_FILE; 
  APEX_COLLECTION.ADD_MEMBER(
    p_collection_name => 'T_FILE',
    p_c001            => :P13_DESC,
    p_blob001         =>V_BLOB -- FNC_CLOB_TO_BLOB(:P13_FILE)
    );

    END;
```

[image: error]

Comment: Hello, do you still need help with this? Why are you using a Dynamic Action? Have you looked at the plug-ins on apex.world to see if one could help? Here are two that might: 1) https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:::NO:710:P710_PLG_ID:DE.DANIELH.DROPZONE 2) https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:::NO:710:P710_PLG_ID:COM.APEXUTIL.FM.COMPONENT

Comment: Hi Dan , i use the dynamic action because i try upload file without submit page and upload multi file but each file has a specific type ,the user must choose file type like below  (two item one file type and the second file browse )                                 
1-file type (costing file /technical file/tender file )
2-file browse

Comment: How does the value of the file type item affect the file browse item? Did you look at the plug-ins?

Comment: sorry dan, In plugin the user can upload multi files  I think , how I can know what the file type ,(costing sheet or technical sheet ....),the user should be choose a file type and upload file

Comment: I think you're trying to say that the value of File Type will determine what types of files can be uploaded via File Browse, is that correct? If so, what types of files do "costing sheet" or "technical sheet" map to? Finally, have you tried the plug-ins to see if there are settings for multiple files or not?

Comment: Hi @jaw , did you found a solution? If you did, can you add your solution here? I'm having the same problem, Trying to insert blob file but same error as you, and can't get the mimetype

Answer (score 2):

My solution works for Files, I guess it will works for images too. There are two steps:

1. Declare the item as 'File Browse' (Lets call it 'P1_FILE_BLOB).

   On item 'storage type' set it to 'Table APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES').
   the file will now will be stored there...
2. In your processes (When u click the 'Add' button), you need to pick that file from the 'APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES'.

   ```
    declare
    filename VARCHAR2(255);
    blob_content blob;
    mimetype VARCHAR2(255);
    begin

    select
       blob_content, filename, mime_type
       into blob_content, filename, mimetype
       from apex_application_temp_files
       where name = :P1_FILE_BLOB;

    apex_collection.add_member(
       p_collection_name => 'T_FILE',
       p_c001 => filename,
       p_c002 => mimetype,
       p_blob001 => blob_content
    ); 
    commit;

    end;
   ```

Of course you need to match 'p_c001'... to your own column in the collection table.

Comment: Can you tell me what value i need to pass at place of  `T_FILE`

Comment: 'T_FILE' is the name of the collection, it is depend on how you called the collection that you have created. If you don't know about collections then look it up, or you can use regular table that holds information for files.